# Inheritance var java

Tags: java

this is the qa:

Define a class called MoreSpeed which extends the following class, and which provides a new method called incSpeed() which adds 1 to the inherited variable length.

this is my answer:

```
public class Speed {
      private int  length = 0;
      public  int  getSpeed () { return length; }
      public  void setSpeed (int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
          length = i;
        }
      }
    }
public class MoreSpeed extends Speed {
private int length;
public int incSpeed() {
return length+1;

}}
```

its says that the syntax is good but the class operation is wrong.
please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. You are shadowing the `length` from `Speed`. Instead, implement `incSpeed` with `getSpeed()` like

```
public int incSpeed() {
    return getSpeed() + 1;
}
```

If you are supposed to modify it as well then use `setSpeed(int)` to do so

```
public int incSpeed() {
    int s = getSpeed() + 1;
    setSpeed(s);
    return s;
}
```